# How can I set the height of my container to extend from the top of the web page down to the bottom?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to web development and am building a website to practice my skills. So far I've been able to customize everything to my liking but I have run into an issue that Google has not been able to help me with.

Basically I'm just trying to replicate this Yahoo page. Notice how in the middle of the page there is a white container that extends from the nav bar all the way down to the end of the page. Then on both sides of the container there is a gray background.

[image: Yahoo]

That's what I want to do for my page below. I want the white container to extend just below the black nav bar. And for it to reach the bottom of the page, but also want it to be responsive depending on the content, so no fixed height.

[image]

I've seen some posts saying to do something like this but that doesn't do anything to my white container. I'm including the full html code below for the page above as well as my CSS. I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7.

```
.container {
margin:0px auto;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 100px;
  background-image: url("NFL-background.png");
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.container .row {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial|Roboto:900|Crimson+Text" rel="stylesheet">

  <title>Make the NFL Great Again</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script type="text/javaScript" src="javaScript.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="navbar-brand">Make the NFL Great Again</div>
      </div>

      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="Wins-Losses.html">Wins / Losses</a></li>
          <li><a href="Points.html">Points</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Hall of Fame <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="LeagueChampions.html">League Champions</a></li>
              <li><a href="AllTimeRecords.html">All-Time Records</a></li>
              <li><a href="SeasonRecords.html">Single-Season Records</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->
  </nav>

  <div class="container content">



    <div class="row">

      <h1>W-L RECORDS</h1>

      <div class="col-sm-2 col-md-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked Uppercase">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">All-Time</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">2017</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">2016</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">2015</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="table-responsive col-lg-10">
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead class="Uppercase">
            <th>Owner</th>
            <th>Seasons</th>
            <th>Matchups</th>
            <th>Wins</th>
            <th>Losses</th>
            <th>Ties</th>
            <th>Win %</th>
            <th><i class="ionicons ion-trophy gold" id="goldWL"></i></th>
            <th><i class="ionicons ion-ribbon-a silver" id="silverWL"></i></th>
            <th><i class="ionicons ion-ribbon-a bronze" id="bronzeWL"></i></th>
          </thead>

          <tr>
            <td>Ivan Ortiz</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>65.6%</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>1</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Cesar Ortiz</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>67.2%</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td>Luis Cardenas</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>32</td>
            <td>13</td>
            <td>19</td>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>40.6%</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>

        </table>

        <div id="footnote">
          *Regular season only, does not include playoffs.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- JQuery and JavaScript CDN -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </div>

</body>
</html
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
height: 100%;
```

Try this:

```
height: 100vh;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So that change made the container extend to the bottom of the page but there is still space between the top of the white container and my nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give height to the body. You can use `100vh` to get the 100% height of the view port, then just add `height: 100%;` to the element you want

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    Some Content
    Some Content
    Some Content
    Some Content
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Doesn't look like I can post code in these replies. So basically I added your suggestions but nothing happened? My white container didn't do anything? Added "height: 100vh;" to my .body class. And added "height: 100%" to my .container .row class.

Comment: @CaliLove Whatever happens or you want to happen after you added the code will be another question, unless it's a clarification to my answer